# Songs/Movies are not being played

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, audio, media-player

The problem I am facing is very odd. None of my songs (.mp3/.avi etc) are not able to run in any of the media players: Windows media player, Windows media center, VLC, DIV etc.

What I have done before posting the question here.

a. Check Device and Drivers and they are working OK and Updated even.

b. Run Sample Audio (Downloaded from Internet) in Adobe Sound-booth and it worked.

c. Plus I run a video in YouTube and I was able to hear it!

d. I am able to hear Windows Error Beeps too..!!!

e. While running Movies I could see playing but not hear it

What could be the problem?

Comment: comment from [Charlie](http://superuser.com/users/22505/charlie): Do any of the media players give you an error message? If so, could you post it?

Comment: Have you checked the obvious - that you haven't got the sound muted and that it's at a reasonable volume?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install some [codecs](http://www.windows7codecs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are different volume controls for different sound production mechanisms. See if you can adjust them via the control panel. You may see a collection of different sliders for different things - make sure they are all on max.

Answer (score 0):

More details please:  Are the files not actually playing or is there a progress bar moving during "playback" and secondly what operating system are you running on.

Windows 7 has a completely different audio stack compared to previous versions of windows; If you are on this OS check all your audio settings (though control panel, or right clicking the speaker in the windows notification area (bottom right)) to see that your media players are set to send audio to the correct media device and that the volume is turned on.